# Cast id to a more specific type or use the id object as is?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am new to Cocoa-Touch. Having a type of `id`, is it more idiomatic to see it cast to a more specific type before messaging the object or is is better style to just invoke operations you know that the object *should* have? Is there a performance hit for using casts extensively in `iOS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting operations will not affect your performance at all. After all, nothing is actually **done** (when your code gets translated to machine code) when you cast an object to another type.

Having said that, I would definitely cast the object before messaging it. It will make your code more readable.